# How to interpret data sheet for an RF 50 Ohm terminator, is it 2 Watt or is it 0.1 Watt

Tags: rf, datasheet

I am trying to find a suitable RF 50 Ohm terminator for my application. I think the following will work:

http://www.amphenolrf.com/media/downloads/7034/132360.pdf

I am a little uncertain though as it states in the "Electrical" section that the impedance is 50 Ohms, the frequency range is 0-18 Ghz and the power rating is 2 Watt. This all fits with in my parameters.

However it has a "Material and Finishes" section and it lists resistance as 100 Ohms and 0.1 Watt. Should I be concerned with this section of the data sheet, is it telling me that really it can only handle 0.1 Watt and 2 Watt is only peak power as opposed to continuous operation? Which if so would put it outside my applications parameters.

Comment: Looks like a datasheet error, I bet the "resistor" line in the materials section is entirely bogus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rated for 2W, it should do 2W unless they note caveats.  I'm not even sure why they felt they had to include information about the resistor -- possibly because they needed it for mil-spec-ness.

If you're worried, get one and put 10V DC on it.  You should see a 200mA current flowing, and the thing shouldn't burn up or otherwise change characteristics significantly.

Expect it to get hot, just because it's SMA-sized and needs to dissipate 2W.  I would expect to get burnt if I casually grabbed it while it was dissipating 2W.

Answer (score 3):

My bet is it's 2 watt. The 100 ohm resistor is listed, but there is probably more than one (or it would be a 100 ohm load) and the resistor is most likely tied to the case. When they are tied to a heatsink, you can run more power through them if the temperature is kept low.

The most important thing would be to follow the temperature rating and keep it below 165C. It's temperature, not power that causes resistors to fail.